# How to pass existing SqlConnection to multiple ObjectContexts

Tags: .net, entity-framework, transactionscope, sqlconnection, objectcontext

I'm passing a SqlConnection to a function. Multiple object contexts are created in each function. I would like to use the single SqlConnection that I passed for all the object contexts somehow so that I will be able to use it under single Transaction scope without turning the distributed transaction service on.

This is the sample code:

```
public bool InsertObjects<T>(TransactionScope transaction, SqlConnection sqlConnection, IEnumerable<T> objectsToInsert)
{
using (EntityConnection conn = GetEntityConnection())
    {
        Type objectContextType;
        ObjectContext objectContext = (ObjectContext) Activator.CreateInstance(objectContextType, new object[] {conn});

        //Some code using the objectContext

    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't pass around a `SqlConnection` - that sounds like your creating it somewhere and then passing around/using it everywhere. I wouldn't do that - I'd much rather pass around the **connection string** and then create a new connection each time I need one.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem like a good approach. Why are you doing this? To make this work you will have to:

- Use the same connection string for all contexts = same database
- Use the same metadata (mapping) for all contexts or pass a separate metadata set for each context
- The connection must be closed until all contexts are created if any context or operation opens the connection, a next context creation will fail

So unless you are using some complex database where mapping was divided into multiple EDMXs this whole concept is wrong. One operation on one database = one unit of work = one context = one connection. In your case it looks like you want to do this with single entity type - WHY?

Moreover passing own collection to object contexts will not allow contexts to handle the connection in the optimal way (releasing it when they don't need it).

Answer (score 0):

A better solution would be a connection pool. 
Create a connection object in object, connect with pooling options on.
The next time you connect it will check to see if an connection is still active and use it.
If there is no connection it will make one.

[Here is a guide on how you use connection pools](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/ADONET_ConnectionPooling.aspx)